How to mock a final class to do nothing when a method from a final class is called using Mockito?
How to mock a final class to return nothing when a function from a final class is called?
In test method:
@InjectMocks
CustomerService customerService;

@Mock
AddCustomerProfile addCustomerProfile;
 
@Test
public void saveCustomer(){
    CustomerDefinition customerDefinition = new CustomerDefinition();
    customerDefinition.setName("Chris");
    customerService.saveCustomer(addCustomerProfile);
}

In CustomerService class:
saveCustomer(AddCustomerProfile addCustomerProfile){
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setName("Messager");
    Webber.addMessageToResponse(message);
}

In Webber class:
public final class Webber{

    public static void addMessageToResponse(Message message){
.
.
.
    }

When customerService.saveCustomer() function is called on the test, I have to mock the behavior of Webber.addMessageToResponse(message) so as to return nothing. I should mock as it should not go inside Webber.addMessageToResponse() method as it is calling another final method inside that method.
I added mockito-inline in pom.xml, but it doesn't actually mock the behavior.

Is it because Webber is final, or because addMessageToResponse(...) is static?  Mockito can mock static methods.  But why is an apparently non-trivial method static?  If you don't have control over Webber, the annoying workaround is to create a wrapper which delegates to the static method.  The wrapper can then be more easily mocked than the static method.

As Webber is final, I cant mock that class. Also, addMessageToResponse(...) is static too. I cant touch the real codebase to create wrapper. I can only write code for test files.

I don't think, that you should mock the static method. Just use it as is. Unless you show us that it has some dependencies which behavior should be mocked.
